# Do the rules have built-in limits on zero-cost powers?

Tags: balance, tri-stat

Using defects and drawbacks, it is quite trivial to get abilities that cost a zero or negative number of build points. Stacking Alternate Form's comes to mind as a way to even do this without defects and drawbacks.

Thus far I have discovered no mechanics in the system to curb this type of building at all - do they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other things in Tri-Stat, that's up to the GM. If she doesn't want you to do it, she'll tell you not to, or specifiy a lower cost limit.

But to answer the question asked: no.